# Simple percentage problem driving me crazy

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, discrete-mathematics, percentages

Ok, so lets say to board a cruise ship it would usually take $60$ to $90$ minutes.

Now it takes only $10$ minutes.

In percentages this is:

$60-10 = \frac{50}{60} = 83.3\%$ reduction (ie. from $60$ minutes to $10$)

$90-10 = \frac{80}{90} = 88.8\%$ reduction (ie. from $90$ minutes to $10$)

Is this correct? For some reason I feel that this is wrong.... and its driving me crazy

"$60-90$ minutes to $10$ minutes is a reduction of $83\%-88\%$ of time it used to take to board a ship."

How can a $30$ minute difference be only just $5\%$ different?

Comment: 83% to 88% reduction in processing time is correct. You can't subtract the percentages to get more information since these percentages have different bases.

Comment: so the correct translation of  the reduction of 60-90 minutes to 10 minutes is the same as, 83% to 88%? thats a 30 minute difference and in percentages its only a 5% difference. can the bases be changed, so it can be more like 58% to 88% reduction?

Comment: 3% to 88% reduction in processing time is correct. I can't drive more information out of these numbers. What you can also do is calculate the old average processing time $(60+90)/2=75$ and compare that to the new time of 10. This would be more meaningful and more easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct - the smaller is final time, the smaller is percentage difference. For example, if time now is 60 minutes, we have $0\%$ decrease from 60 minutes, but $33\%$ decrease from 90 minutes. It, at other hand, new time is almost zero, then decrease from either 60 or 90 minutes is almost $100\%$.

What is constant (independent of new time) is *ratio of percents left* (=what percent is new time of any of old). For example, if new time is 60 - it's $100\%$ of 60 but only $67\%$ of 90 - so ration is 3:2. In your case, it's $\sim 16\%$ vs $\sim 11\%$ - again 3:2.

Comment: Im trying to understand, so basically.. to board a cruise ship it would usually take 60-90 minutes which now takes 10 minutes.

But your saying 11-16% reduction in time

Comment: No, I am saying new time is $16\%$ of 60 minutes, but $11\%$ of 90.

Comment: So whats the percentage way of saying 60-90 minutes reduced to 10 minutes in percentages? (ie. something like 60%-88% reduction). & how would you calculate something like this?

Comment: It's not clear what does it mean. You had max and min time. New time is $83\%$ less than old min time, and $88\%$ than old max time. Or you can say that old min time was $500\%$ more than new time, and old max was $800\%$ greater.

Comment: I don't know it just doesn't look right when: the base is 10 minutes, taking 60-90 minutes from base and then converting to percentage of 83%-88%.

Comment: When we say "something decreased by $n\%$" the base is old value, not a new. So bases are $60\%$ in one case and $90\%$ in other. And yes, even big difference in bases can give small differences in percents.